# How to make edittext autofocus after showing a Toast?

Tags: android, focus, android-edittext, autofocus

I have a EditText that reads a 13 digit barcode. What I want to do is to keep the virtual keyboard shown on the screen and the EditText to always have focus. The following code let me write the barcode and search for a product when enter key is pressed, and it works well. But if I type a barcode with less then 13 digits or the barcode typed does not exist in my database, I want to show the user a Toast, informing him of it. After displaying the Toast, I want the EditText to gain focus again automatically, letting the user just type the barcode again. After showing the Toast, I tried the requestFocus() method, but it didn't work. The soft keyboard is always shown, but after the Toast, I can't type in the EditText again unless I touch on the EditText. How can I do this?

```
    final EditText procura_codbar = (EditText)
                findViewById(R.id.procurar_produto_codbar);
    procura_codbar.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                    && (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {

                String codbar = procura_codbar.getText().toString();
                if (codbar.length()<13){   
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                           "type a 13 digit barcode",
                           Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else{
                    if (bdh!=null){
                        bdh.closedb(); bdh.close();
                    }
                    bdh = new DBHelper(MainActivity.this);
                    Log.i("CODBAR", codbar);
                    produto prod_ = bdh.getProduto(codbar);
                    if (prod_!=null){
                        showDialogPreco(prod_);
                        procura_codbar.setText("");
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                                                     "Product not found",
                                                     Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        procura_codbar.setSelection(codbar.length());
                    }
                }
                procura_codbar.requestFocus();
                procura_codbar.setSelection(codbar.length());
            }

            return false;
        }
    });
```

And here is the XML:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/procurar_produto_codbar"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:inputType="textNoSuggestions|number"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:maxLength="13"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tv_procura_codbar" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Messing with this, I found the problem. Heres the solution:

```
return true;
```

Now it works...

Comment: Where did you place the "return true" statement? If you simply replaced the "return false" with it, none of the keys you pressed would appear in the EditText.

Comment: You may also want to add 'android:singleLine="true"' to your XML.

Comment: You're right, I forgot to put "singleLine=true" in the XML in the question, but I did that in my code. And yes, I've changed the "return false;" at the end to "return true;"

Comment: If wanted, I can post my exact code, which is working, but it's not much different from this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put this code right next to that Toast Message:

```
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                       "type a 13 digit barcode",
                       Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

procura_codbar.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
procura_codbar.setFocusable(true);
procura_codbar.requestFocus();
procura_codbar.setSelection(codbar.length());
```

This worked for me. Also  you need to remove the ***procura_codbar.requestFocus();*** at the bottom of the code.

Comment: Thanks. I tried this. I Typed a two digit barcode, it showed me the toast when I pressed "enter key". I then pressed "del key" and other digits, but it didn't work, as del and the digits didn't appear on the edittext.

Comment: Can you translate your toast messages in English, as I am unable to proceed from there...

Comment: Ok got it...let me check then .

Comment: Strange, didn't work either. I've updated my question with your suggestions. Please take a look.

Comment: @user1531978-Then I suggest you to debug ur complete code, as it may b generating some exception. This code works on my emulator.

Comment: Okay, I set the breakpoint at setSelection(), and when debug stopped there, I typed some digits. After resuming debug, the typed digits appeared. It seems I'm losing focus somewhere...

Comment: It means that code is correct. Something else is not in place. So shift breakpoint to Toast Msg. That will help u.

Comment: Thanks, NilayOnAndroid. I managed to get it to work. I put procura_codbar.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
procura_codbar.setFocusable(true);
procura_codbar.requestFocus(); on a function, and it worked. Don't know why it didn't work directly though...

Answer (score 2):

I've only been able to get the focus back to the `EditText` by delaying momentarily before calling the `requestFocus()` method:

```
final Handler handler = new Handler();
final EditText myEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);

myEditText.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        // See if user presses enter
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {

            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You pressed enter!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 

            // Put focus back in the EditText after brief delay                  
            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {                 
                    myEditText.requestFocus();

                    // Select all text
                    myEditText.setSelection(0, myEditText.getText().length());                  
                }                   
            }, 200);

            return true;                    
        }

        return false;
    }       
});
```

Comment: Thank you! That handler was the only thing that worked for me.